# Simple JS/JSON not working with Angular

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm starting to learn Angular JS, and I wrote the following code to display name, age and profession. I'm using Angular 1.5.

```html
<!-- View -->

<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <h1> {{author.name}} </h1>
  <p>{{author.age + " " + author.profession}}</p>
</div>


<!-- MODAL -->
<script>
  function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.author = {
      'name': 'Muhammad',
      'age': '35',
      'profession': 'Software Engineer'
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you pass the function `MyController` to angular.module("[your module]").controller("MyController",`MyController`) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is angular module and ng-app directive in your HTML.

Simply follow this free course.
https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

Simple sample code:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1> {{author.name}} </h1>
    <p>{{author.age + " " + author.profession}}</p>
</div>

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.author = {
                'name': 'Muhammad',
                'age': '35',
                'profession': 'Software Engineer'
            }
        });
</script>

<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a module:

```
var app = angular.module("main", []); 
app.controller("MyController", MyController);

<html ng-app="main">
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <h1> {{author.name}} </h1>
  <p>{{author.age + " " + author.profession}}</p>
</div>

</html>
```

working example:
http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/YWmWNo